# how to get count(*) value in local temp variable in dynamic sql (ORACLE PLSQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want to get `count(*)` value in dynamic plsql statement.
We can write static stmt as:

```
select count(*) into tmp_cnt from table_info where nbr_entry='0123456789';
```

but how to get `tmp_cnt` value while writing the dynamic sql stament?
or any other way to get `count(*)` value into `tmp_cnt` variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve it with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ... RETURNING INTO:

```
function count_rows(p_table_name varchar2)
  return number
is
  l_count number;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || p_table_name into l_count;
  return l_count;
end count_rows;
```

Comment: This does not work in Oracle. ORA-06547: RETURNING clause must be used with INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe different oracle version, but what worked for me was:

```
...
execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || p_table_name into l_count;
...
```

Comment: Note possible sql injection risk

Comment: This works for me on 12c while the accepted answer returns ORA-06547: RETURNING clause must be used with INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements.